# Json_encode takes so much time for convert to JSON as response

Tags: php, json

Here is my scenario, for example i have 4000 contacts (return 271257 lines after json_encode) in database, i have called

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

But it takes 35-40 second to return response as JSON. So my question is, are there any another options for decrease converting process to json. So i can make fast application.
I have tried a lot by calling below functions

```
1) json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

2) 
header('Content-Type: application/json')
echo json_encode($response);

3)
header('Content-Type: application/json')
echo json_encode($response); die;
```

> This is the sample data of single contact

```
{
            "address": {
                "primary": {
                    "id": "",
                    "address1": "",
                    "address2": "",
                    "city": "",
                    "state": "",
                    "zipcode": "",
                    "country": "",
                    "primary-address": ""
                },
                "secondary": {
                    "id": "",
                    "address1": "",
                    "address2": "",
                    "city": "",
                    "state": "",
                    "zipcode": "",
                    "country": "",
                    "secondary-address": ""
                }
            },
            "groups": [],
            "regions": [],
            "links": [],
            "phone": [
                {
                    "type_id": 2,
                    "phone_type": "Mobile",
                    "country_code": "us",
                    "value": "+1 1830593231",
                    "is_primary": 1,
                    "country_code_value": "+1"
                }
            ],
            "social": [],
            "email": [
                {
                    "type_id": 2,
                    "type": "Work",
                    "value": "cron_4000@gmail.com",
                    "is_primary": 1
                }
            ],
            "tags": [],
            "action": {
                "is_favourite": 0,
                "is_following": 0,
                "is_stay": 0,
                "kit_expired": 0
            },
            "access": [],
            "activity_count": [],
            "contact_id": 5768,
            "type": 0,
            "salutation_id": 1,
            "assigned_to": 1,
            "first_name": "Cron 4000",
            "assigned_name": "Krunal Patel",
            "created_date": null,
            "primary_address_id": 0,
            "secondary_address_id": 0,
            "modified_date": null,
            "contact_modified_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "created_by": 1
        }
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data with us? How do these contacts look, how is it structured?

Comment: Use server side caching ..

Comment: Can you please give me a reference of code or site?

Comment: paginate your request like ask for 100 contact at a time

Comment: @ Vanojx1 : Thnks for answer but i want all the data because the concept is that when user logged in to application firstly sync all the data from server. So first time i have to give whole data.

Comment: Well then you will simply have to accept, that transferring the “whole data” every single time on login, just takes time. Or you’ll have to find a smarter way, instead of sending the “whole data” each time ... for example you could only send the _changes_, that differ from the data the user already downloaded last time.

Comment: this process if for first time when user login into the mobile end. Other wise it is work with the sync date

Answer (score 0):

its not json_encode fault.if you run below code you can see that in less than 3 seconds it gonna finished.its because of output size and rendering time that you show to the user.you can paginate your output and don't show all of them together

```
<?php
$str = [];
for($i = 0;$i<4000;$i++){
    $str[] = "sample data";
}
$json = json_encode($str);

echo strlen($json);
```

Comment: need to pass all the data, pagination concept is not work here.

Comment: you can't use ajax to do lazy load and when user scroll position it's at the end of the page load more data again?

Comment: this data is passed to mobile end , so lazy load is not gone to work here

Comment: why you can't use lazy load on the mobile devices? you can't call any ajax?

Comment: Thnks for answer, but without any pagination or lazy loader is there any option to minimize time of response by calling encode_json()

Comment: @ashish There is no function called `encode_json()`. You should fix your data structure if the call to `json_encode()` needs 40seconds for you.